# How to rename files in current directory and its subdirectories using bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, rename, subdirectory

I'm able to use the 'rename' command to add the missing character to all filenames in the current directory like this:

```
echo "Renaming files..."
rename -v "s/^abcd124(.+)/abcd1234$1/" *.wav.gz;
echo "Done."
```

However, I'd like to do this for the current directory **and** all its subdirectories. I tried this:

```
echo "Renaming files..."
for dir in $(find ./ -type d); do
    rename -v "s/^$dir\/abcd124(.+)/$dir\/abcd1234$1/" *.wav.gz;
done;
echo "Done."
```

However, if the `$dir` variable contains any of these special characters: `{}[]()^$.|*+?\` then they are not escaped properly with \ and my script fails.

What would be the best way to solve this problem? Also, what do you guys think of using `awk` to solve this problem (advantages/disadvantages?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also try:

```
find . -name "*.wav.gz" | xargs rename -v "s/abcd124*/abcd1234$1/"
```

It works on newer Unix systems with "xargs" command available. Note that I edited the regular expression slightly.

Comment: Will fail for filenames containing blanks.

Comment: This is true. Although none of the files I need to rename right now have spaces in the filename, files that I work with in the future might. How can I make the script account for spaces in the filenames?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
find ./ -type d -execdir rename -v "s/^abcd124(.+)/abcd1234\1/" *.wav.gz ";"
```

Find does already provide an iterator over your files - you don't need `for` around it or `xargs` behind , which are often seen. Well - in rare cases, they might be helpful, but normally not.

Here, -execdir is useful. Gnu-find has it; I don't know if your find has it too.

But you need to make sure not to have a *.wav.gz-file in the dir you're starting this command, because else your shell will expand it, and hand the expanded names over to rename.

Note: I get an warning from rename, that I should replace \1 with $1 in the regex, but if I do so, the pattern isn't catched. I have to use \1 to make it work.

Here is another approach. Why at all search for directories, if we search for wav.gz-files?

```
find . -name "*.wav.gz" -exec rename -v "s/^abcd124(.+)/abcd1234\1/" {} ";"
```

Comment: It didn't work! :( I ran it and it didn't rename anything. I tried removing the quotes around "*.wav.gz" and in that case it renamed one file to abcd1234 (didn't recognize the $1) and then couldn't rename the others because they conflicted with abcd1234. Thanks for your suggestion though, I learned a lot. Any other ideas?

Comment: @jessica: You're right. I changed code and explanation, see the last 2 paragraphs.

Comment: This didn't work either - it gives me the warning for each file in the starting directory, doesn't rename them, and doesn't look in its subdirectories. Also, for my purposes the script will need to be run from within the starting directory and can't be printing out a warning for every file. It needs to be bulletproof!

Comment: Well, I tested it and it worked for me. Now I made a second approach (last 2 lines) which I tested too. It works too, and too gives me the warning, but doesn't work if I take the warning seriously. Of course you can surpess the warning by appending `2>/dev/null`. Or you open the perl-script which rename is, and surpress/correct it there. Or file a bug report to againts rename. Or rewrite the parts of rename, which you need, but I wouldn't. I would live with the warnings. Whether a program is bulletproof does not depend on warning messages, I can assert to you, but I would be sceptical too.

Comment: The last script you gave me didn't work for me either - it gave warnings for all the files to be renamed (including files with spaces in the filename), but didn't rename them!

Comment: Well - I don't understand why. I have `find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2`, but `rename` doesn't support a version flag. `less $(which rename)` reveals multiple, different organized version strings, `# Revision 1.5  1998/12/18 16:16:31  rmb1` being the newest.

Answer (score 1):

In `bash` 4:

```
shopt -s globstar
rename -v "s/^$dir\/abcd124(.+)/$dir\/abcd1234$1/" **/*.wav.gz;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just be aware that Gentoo Linux has its rename utility points to

http://developer.berlios.de/project/showfiles.php?group_id=413

by its ebuild

http://sources.gentoo.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/gentoo-x86/sys-apps/rename/rename-1.3.ebuild?view=markup

for Debian or maybe Ubuntu,

`rename` is `/usr/bin/prename`, which is a perl script

See `rename --help` before your move.